# Add <select> options based on the value of a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How I can add options to a select field based on the value of a text input?

This is my input text:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" size="30" />
```

This is my element I want to add to:

```
<span id="span_combo">
     <select name="foo" id="combo">
           <option value="1">1</option>  
           <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
</span>
```

This is my current JS:

```
$("#amount").keyup(function(){
        var flag;
        $("#combo").show("slow");
        var a = $("#amount").val();
        if(a==""){
            $("#span_combo select").remove(true);
        }
        var i;
        for(i=1;i<=a-1;i++){
                $("#span_combo").append($("#span_combo select").first().clone(true));
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you trying to add more options to the selectbox? or update a different element in the document?

Comment: My fault... forgot about your rogue input box at the top. would you be able to rebuild the entire array of options from 0 each time the input box is updated are you restricted to appending to the original array?

Comment: I want to update different element in the document, not to add more options to the selectbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it

Live demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/NdpuM/1/

```
$("#amount").keyup(function(){
    var $combo = $('#combo');
    $combo.html('');
    var value = parseInt($('#amount').val(), 10);
    for (i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        var $option = $('<option>').val(i).html(i);
        $combo.append($option);
    }
});
```

Basically, clear the select box everytime there is a keydown and repopulate it. You could optimize this more by adding a few checks to see whether it's the same value

Comment: Never ever use parseInt without the ",10)" at the end

Comment: @regilero good point. I forgot it one of my earlier answers as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
$("#amount").keyup(function() {
        var current = $("#combo option").length;
        if(current < $(this).val()) {
            for(var i = current + 1;i<=$(this).val();i++) {
                $("#combo").append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
            }
        } else {
            for(var i=(parseInt($(this).val(),10)+1);i<=current;i++) {
                $('#combo option[value="'+i+'"]').remove();
            }
        }
    });
```

You might want to add input verification to this function, but it does what you want if you use it right.

EDIT: Just to clarify, this code doesn't clear the whole select box on every keyup event, it just adds new options or removes the last ones to get the specified amount of values.

Comment: Same remark as for JohnP, you forgot ',10)' in the parseInt expression

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebuild the entire array:

```
$("#amount").keyup(function(){
        $("#combo").show("slow");
        var a = $("#amount").val();
        if(a==""){
            $("#span_combo select").remove(true);
        }


        $('#combo').empty();
        for(var i=1;i<=a-1;i++){
            $('<option />').attr('value', i)
                           .text(i)
                           .appendTo($('#combo'));
        }
    });
```